# Graph API: AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I am using graph API to access oneDrive, in order to copy/download/.... files.
All works fine if I use my personal account, but as soon as I try to use my company business account I get

> AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application: '2d674cb8-8a33-4bfa-860a-33490fb73ca9'.

Authenticaion url is similar to:

tps://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=&redirect_uri=https://server/.../deeplink&scope=Files.ReadWrite.All

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Did you use the same configuration and authentication request for both personal account and company account?

Comment: Yes, all the configuration are the exactly the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error usually occurs when the redirect_uri in the authorization request mismatch the redirect url configured in Azure portal.

The redirect_uri in your request is `https://server/.../deeplink`, so please check the redirect url in Azure portal.

[image]

Comment: They are exactly the same. No difference!

Comment: @mina Can you paste the authentication request here?

Comment: Is possible some setting like proxy or other security settings in company microsoft account causes this issue? I cannot think of anything else?

Comment: yes, I will post it here as soon as I reach to the office, but the request is fine, because it works fine with my personal account, if I just change the tenant, client and secret code to my personal account all is fine. I really thinks it is something related to azure settings in the company business account.

Comment: @mina So you are using two applications registered in Azure portal? One for your personal account and the other for tenant account, right?

Comment: I have one my personal account in microsoft, I setup an app under azure portal all works fine. After coding is finished I want to use this in real situation, so I created another app in azure portal of our company business account, and nothing works here. I keep getting the above error. All setups are the same. At least I think they are the same, except if there is another security setup in the company business account.

Comment: @mina I don't think there is any security setup, does your another app work for your personal account?

Comment: @mina Have you tried your personal account with the new app?

Comment: Do you think the request I am sending for business account is correct?https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=our_client_id&redirect_uri=our_redirect_uri&scope=Files.ReadWrite.All

Comment: Also, I should add that, with this request, I get authorization code, show me the microsoft login page, after I login all goes wrong when it should redirect to the reply_url.

Comment: @mina Yes, it is correct. Can you replace the redirect uri in the portal with the redirect_uri in your auth request and try again?

Comment: @mina Can you show me the screenshot of the redirect url part in azure portal?

Comment: redirect_url basically is the same for both my personal account and business account. it is url to our application.

Comment: Strangely I am not allow to add any image. Stackoverflow doesn't let me.

Comment: The redirect_url is the same in my personal account app. And it is https://. I edited  url.

Comment: @mina If it still doesn't work, you can register a new application and try again.

Comment: Yes, I tried localhost for both sides, again it works for personal account, but not for business account. I'll try to create another app.

Comment: Tony, creating new app works :) and I really don't have any explanation why previous one didn't work. but many thanks for help and your time.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if some security settings in our company microsoft account causes this issue? I also set these parameters in manifest to true"oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": true, "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true
I cannot think of anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Tony, Per your request, I added image of url here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEHBm.png